# How can I disable password on termina?

Tags: password, sudo

I am trying to install a software through terminal. It asks  for my password and i have given the correct password but still it says wrong password. Then i removed all kind off password from my login account. but still it asks for the password. i am using Ubuntu 14.04. Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it is asking for the root password. Are you the administrator on the computer? If you are, try using passwords like `Root` or `Password` because it sounds like it isn't using your password. Sadly since you are messing with system files when installing software, there is no way to disable the password.

Hint: Instead of typing `Sudo` in front of every command, try typing in `Sudo -s` and when your done being root, just type `exit`